# Chrome keeps crashing after updates

Tags: apt, login, google-chrome

I'm a chrome user and an enthusiast but few days ago I made Ubuntu get some updates using `Update Manager`, then I turned off my notebook and when I restarted it, I tried to start Chrome which after a few seconds turned the screen completely black, and some errors appeared for few seconds and then I got logged off, and had to re-login,
and when I opened Chrome again the same thing happened!

I've uninstalled it with Synaptic and did complete cleanings before re-installing Chrome but nothing succeeded. Now I can't use either Chromium and Chrome, but Firefox works. It's a very strange thing, never happened to me before and I don't know what to do because I had all my bookmarks syncronized in Chrome!

Please help if you can :)

Answer (score 2):

If your bookmarks are the only thing you are worried about, you can recover them from 
the terminal by running `cp ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks* ~/.` This will copy your Chrome bookmarks to your home folder directory.

You should sync Chrome through Google, it is one of the major selling points of chrome. http://www.guidingtech.com/3125/chrome-bookmarks-sync/

I also recommend you do the following: open the terminal and run 
Chrome. It will crash but give you an output of what may have happened. 
You can use the command

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

to see what may have gone wrong.

My advice for you though is to make a new profile: Briefly, after backing up your data, open nautilus (home folder), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to display hidden files,  navigate to `.config/` and delete both `chromium` and `google-chrome` folders and start Chrome over. A totally clean profile will be recreated automatically. Let us know what happened, so I can improve my answer.

The official version on creating a new profile in Chrome is here: [Create a new browser user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059).

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me, and I found the following user who was able to resolve the issue:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/xcKqyLSij5A/OGSpv2FaLZoJ

Could it be that in your case, as in mine and the above user's, you tried updating your NVIDIA drivers and something went wrong? If so a reinstall of the same driver might help.

Comment: Yes, updating the nvidia driver fixed the crashes for me.